# BeanCreationException in grails deployment on linux env

Tags: mysql, linux, tomcat, grails

I am trying to deploy a war file created using grails on tomcat6. The same war files works just alright on my windows machine it does give me following exception with prod linux environment

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
```

and

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
```

I have already gone through 
[How do I fix the org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException error in my Grails application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725447/how-do-i-fix-the-org-springframework-beans-factory-beancreationexception-error-i)

and

[Grails transactionManager exception on Run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194910/grails-transactionmanager-exception-on-run)

but it die not help

Answer (score 1):

Scroll to the end where it says `Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'`. It's usually the case with Grails exceptions that the top-level text is generic and useless, and the real cause is further down near the bottom.

I'm guessing you put the MySQL driver jar in the lib directory, but Grails didn't find it there. You shouldn't use jars unless they're not available in an online repo, and the MySQL driver certainly is. In fact it's the sample entry in `BuildConfig.groovy` in the `dependencies` block. Uncomment that, optionally updating to the latest version (5.1.28), and redeploy your war file. Make sure it's there in the file, in WEB-INF/lib